# Log in activity development in android using php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, android-asynctask

I am working on login activity in android app server side in php and database mysql. Before login I have to show the user name in json format in the activity. I have done it. But here some problem in my code I got the php response true but cannot login. Please

```js
10-29 04:00:29.401: D/LightsService(381): Excessive delay setting light: 96ms
10-29 04:00:29.801: D/LightsService(381): Excessive delay setting light: 56ms
10-29 04:00:32.521: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(497): Dictionary info: dictionary = contacts.en_US.dict ; version = ? ; date = ?
10-29 04:00:33.681: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.681: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.681: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.681: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.681: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:33.691: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
10-29 04:00:33.791: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2110): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
10-29 04:00:33.791: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2110):   in android.widget.EditText{b1dc2668 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,209-768,288 #7f090004 app:id/password}
10-29 04:00:33.791: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2110):   0: sent at 6977802000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=6977802, downTime=6977716, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
10-29 04:00:39.451: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.451: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.451: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.451: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.451: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.451: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.461: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.461: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.461: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.461: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.471: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.471: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.471: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.471: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.501: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:39.511: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
10-29 04:00:39.581: D/dalvikvm(2110): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 4% free 3529K/3652K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
10-29 04:00:39.591: I/dalvikvm-heap(2110): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.582MB for 1127536-byte allocation
10-29 04:00:39.621: D/dalvikvm(2110): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 4628K/4756K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
10-29 04:00:40.451: W/SingleClientConnManager(2110): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
10-29 04:00:40.451: W/SingleClientConnManager(2110): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
10-29 04:00:40.541: I/System.out(2110): Response : User Found{"username":"asd","password":"asd"}
10-29 04:00:40.731: I/Choreographer(2110): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-29 04:00:41.441: W/System.err(2110): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-29 04:00:41.531: D/dalvikvm(2110): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 6% free 5001K/5280K, paused 85ms, total 88ms
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at com.example.helloworld.LoginForm$MyTask.onPostExecute(LoginForm.java:154)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at com.example.helloworld.LoginForm$MyTask.onPostExecute(LoginForm.java:1)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-29 04:00:41.541: W/System.err(2110):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-29 04:00:41.551: W/System.err(2110):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-29 04:00:41.561: W/System.err(2110):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 04:00:41.561: I/Choreographer(2110): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-29 04:00:41.791: W/InputMethodManagerService(381): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b1fbfec8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b206b6d0
10-29 04:00:44.821: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.821: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.821: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.821: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-29 04:00:44.831: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
10-29 04:00:44.881: W/InputMethodManagerService(381): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b1e82b78 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b206b6d0
```

```css
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="mydatabase";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase")
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
 
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $localhost);
 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 if($rows == 0) { 
 echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
}
if($rows!=0)
 {
 $arr = array("username" => $username);
 echo json_encode($_POST);
 //print json_encode($arr);
 }
?>
```

```html
package com.example.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class LoginForm extends Activity {
    Button b,bt;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php";
     
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        JSONperser jsonParser = new JSONperser();
 
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        bt= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginForm.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                          
                        }
                      }).start();  
                 MyTask task = new MyTask();
                 task.execute("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php");
            }
        });
    
    
     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg) {
        
       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this, Register.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   
 
   }
 
  });
    }
    void login(){
        try{            
              
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // e.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
             
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginForm.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                 
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginForm.this, Userpage.class));
            }
            else{
                showAlert();                
            }
             
        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        LoginForm.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginForm.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }
  private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

     


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      

      
      try {
       JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(result);
       JSONObject temp = myJson.getJSONObject("arr");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.getString("username"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       //JSONArray myArray = temp.getJSONArray("arr"); 
       
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
   
     }


     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);
      ResponseHandler<String> handler =
      new BasicResponseHandler();
      try {
       return(client.execute(httpGet, handler));
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return "no";
     }
     

    }
}
```

! help. Thanks in advance.